Telerik ASP.NET MVC UI StockChart/Chart adds dates to dataseries
I have a straightforward chart, which is a standard stock chart, and everything is functioning correctly. However, it seems that the Telerik MVC UI chart is generating additional dates in an effort to maintain its tick steps. Is there a way to prevent this? My dataset does not include the dates circled below.
Chart Result
Thanks
I've tried every argument for categories and reading Telerik's documentation.
@(Html.Kendo().StockChart < IATradeBLL.Model.TestResearchStockPriceHistory >
  (Model.TestResearchStockPriceHistories.Take(30))
  .Name("stockChart")
  .Title(@Model.TestResearchStock.Ticker)
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .ServerOperation(false))
  .DateField("PriceDate")
  .SeriesColors(new string[] {
    "",
    "GREEN"
  })
  .Series(series => {
    series.Candlestick(s => s.PriceOpen, s => s.PriceHigh, s => s.PriceLow, s =>     s.PriceClose, s => s.UpPrice, s => s.DownPrice);
series.Line(s => s.EMANine);
  })

  .Navigator(nav => nav
.Series(series => {
  series.Bar(s => s.Volume);
    })
  )
)

